# What is the use of "!" mark in perl regular expression?

Tags: regex, boost-regex

I'm using the boost library for regular expression.

What is the use of "!" mark in the Perl regular expression?

What does it denote?

Comment: Can you show us an example of how you're seeing it used? It means different things in different contexts.

Comment: A suggestion would be to insert your regular expression into http://www.regex101.com/ and read the explanation part. Because it is based on PCRE, much of it can be directly translated to Perl.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By itself it means nothing special, it just matches `!`. It can be combined with other symbols to mean other things:

- `(?!...)` is a negative lookahead - it matches if the following characters do not match the "..." portion
- `(?<!...)` is a negative lookbehind - it matches if the preceding characters do not match the "..." portion